# Confused about writing a program for placing some modified queen-type pieces on an 8 x 8 board

Tags: java, algorithm

To this question:

> The superqueen is a chess piece that can move like a queen, but also like a knight. What is the maximal number of superqueens on an 8X8 chessboard such that no one can capture an other?

I want to write a brute force algorithm to find the maximum. Here's what I wrote:

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean chess[][];

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        chess = new boolean[8][8];
        chess[0][0] = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                /*Loop to check various possibilities*/
                if (!checkrow(i) && !checkcolumn(j) && !checkdiagonals(i, j) && !checkknight(i, j)) {
                    if (i != 0 || j != 0) {
                        chess[i][j] = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }/*printing the array*/

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                System.out.print(((chess[i][j]) ? "T" : "x") + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /*All working fine here*/
    public static boolean checkrow(int a) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (chess[a][i]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*All working fine here*/
    public static boolean checkcolumn(int a) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (chess[i][a]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*All working fine here*/
    public static boolean checkdiagonals(int pi, int pj) {

        int i = pi - Math.min(pi, pj);
        int j = pj - Math.min(pi, pj);

        for (int k = i, l = j; k < 8 && l < 8; k++, l++) {
            if (chess[k][l]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        int i_2 = pi - Math.min(pi, pj);
        int j_2 = pj + Math.min(pi, pj);

        for (int k = i_2, l = j_2; k < 8 && l > 1; k++, l--) {
            if (chess[k][l]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /*Not All working fine here try commenting out this method above so that that it doesn't run during the check*/
    public static boolean checkknight(int pi, int pj) {

        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                if (0 <= pi + 2 * i && pi + 2 * i <= 8 && 0 <= pj + j && pj + j <= 8) {
                    if (chess[pi + 2 * i][pj + j]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                if (0 <= pi + i && pi + i <= 8 && 0 <= pj + 2 * j && pj + 2 * j <= 8) {
                    if (chess[pi + i][pj + 2 * i]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have two questions:

- My algorithm for **checkknight** looks for all knight positions, is it wrong? or there is some coding error.Everything is working fine when I comment out it and I get a nice solution.
- Secondly it'll result only in one solution.For other solutions I have to offset(or change position) of other pieces bit by bit after each mega-loop of this, I am confused about implementing it. My instincts guide me that I need to change whole of the code. Is there a modification or a way to do it?

**Additional Thoughts:** I think we would add to a counter each time we place a piece and add to a long array and output the maximum and array after storing the relevant data.

**Code Location:** You may view/edit/fork/download it at **http://ideone.com/gChD8a**

Comment: You can scan the internet for suggestions as to the optimal way to do this. Also, you need to use recursion for the solution to this. Third your question is too broad for this forum. You need to ask specific questions that can be answered definitively

Comment: The tests `<=8` look suspicious. Shouldn't they be `<8`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat maybe you're right because it's a 8x8 array so maximum is i=7?

Comment: Yes, if you attempt to access index 8 of an 8-element array, you'll get an exception.

Comment: I'm interested in this. Out of curiosity, have you you considered working backwards from the standard [8Q Puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle)? If you start with the classic 8Q 12 solutions, you can very quickly cover all the cases (12 solutions, 8 queens to remove = 96 boards with 7 queens, 672 boards with 6 queens (of which at least one is the solution), and so on. I can write a demonstration of this later if that's an option. Brute forcing this is remarkably operation-heavy IIRC.

Comment: The brute force algorithm is simple. Add a queen to a space on the board, remove all the spaces she can capture from consideration. Add the next queen to the board in the first empty space, and repeat. When you cannot add any more queens because there are no spaces to put them, try moving the last queen you placed to the next valid space. When the first queen has been placed in each space in the top left quadrant, your max is calculated (since the board is symmetrical both ways, we only have to calculate one quarter of it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This a rough brute-force method starting from the opposite direction, i.e. from the solved eight-queens puzzle. This will allow us to find a bunch of viable solutions.

The brute-force technique for going from a single superqueen to *potentially* 8 seems to be especially complex due to the knight's traversal. Based on the runs, about 60% of the viable paths for normal queens are invalid with superqueens. So if we were to instead brute force normal queens, and then work backwards, that is potential time saved for finding a solution, and we can better determine the run-time. Because we know normal queens is easier.

We start off with the 12 fundamental solutions, we would then use these as inputs. Solving normal queens is outside this, but the wiki page has a fantastic article describing everything.

In my case, I stored them as Strings representing the coordinate of the queen (the rows are indices).

So: "17468253" = A1, B7, C4, D6, E8, F2, G5, H3

By brute-forcing the opposite direction from solved queens, we only have to test at most 12 x 8! possible solutions. Because order doesn't matter, additional optimization could occur by eliminating duplicate boards and solutions for processing.

First up, checkKnight, which appears to be your source of confusion. Using absolute values, you can reasonably determine whether or not a piece is within knight's range by checking whether the X offset is 2 and Y offset is 1, or vice versa. You've made a complex checkKnight function to check each individual location and whether or not a piece is on the border. Working the other way by hitscanning each queen to each other queen is logically simpler and less of a nightmare to debug.

#### Queen class

```
public class Queen {
    int i, j;

    public Queen(int i, int j) {
        this.i = i;
        this.j = j;
    }

    public boolean checkKnight(Queen queen) { // if any queen meets another
                                                // queen at 2 and 1 offset, we
                                                // eliminate it.
        return (Math.abs(i - queen.i) == 2 && Math.abs(j - queen.j) == 1)
                || (Math.abs(i - queen.i) == 1 && Math.abs(j - queen.j) == 2);
    }
}
```

This board has been modified since I originally posted. It takes a String input and converts it to a full chessboard. It has some minor work towards the potential any-size board, but right now it handles child board creation. When a child board is created, the queens are passed by reference rather than making a whole new set of queens. A total of 96 queens are stored in memory, 1 for each one on the original 12-board solution. Not perfectly optimized, but better than 96 -> 672 -> 4032 -> ...

#### Board class

```
public class Board {
    static int boardSize = 8;
    ArrayList<Queen> queens = new ArrayList<Queen>();

    public Board(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            queens.add(new Queen(i, s.charAt(i) - 49)); // you could implement
                                                        // base 16 here, for
                                                        // example, for a 15x15
                                                        // board
        }
    }

    public Board(Board b) { // duplicates the board, but keeps references to
                            // queens to conserve memory, only 96 total queens
                            // in existence through search!
        for (Queen q : b.queens) {
            queens.add(q);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkForImpact() {
        for (int i = 0; i < queens.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < queens.size(); j++) {
                if (queens.get(i).checkKnight(queens.get(j))) { // just check
                                                                // for any
                                                                // queens
                                                                // intersecting,
                                                                // one hit is
                                                                // enough
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public ArrayList<Board> getChildBoards() { // create child boards with a
                                                // single queen removed
        ArrayList<Board> boards = new ArrayList<Board>();
        for (int i = 0; i < queens.size(); i++) {
            boards.add(new Board(this));
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Board b : boards) {
            b.queens.remove(i);
            i++;
        }
        return boards;
    }

    public String drawBoard() {
        String s = "";
        char[][] printableBoard = new char[boardSize][boardSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                printableBoard[i][j] = '_';
            }
        }
        for (Queen q : queens) {
            printableBoard[q.i][q.j] = 'Q';
        }
        s += "  A B C D E F G H\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            s += (8 - i) + "|";
            for (int j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
                s += printableBoard[i][j];
                s += "|";
            }
            s += "\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

#### Test class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    static String[] boards = { "24683175", "17468253", "17582463", "41582736",
            "51842736", "31758246", "51468273", "71386425", "51863724",
            "57142863", "63184275", "53172864" }; // all 12 solutions for the 8
                                                    // queens problem
    static ArrayList<Board> boardObjects = new ArrayList<Board>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String queens : boards) { // create starter boards
            boardObjects.add(new Board(queens));
        }

        int i;
        ArrayList<Board> foundBoards = null;
        for (i = 8; i > 0; i--) {
            ArrayList<Board> newBoards = new ArrayList<Board>();
            foundBoards = new ArrayList<Board>();
            for (Board b : boardObjects) {
                if (b.checkForImpact()) { // if any queen intercepts we get
                                            // children
                    ArrayList<Board> boardsToBeAdded = b.getChildBoards(); // pass
                                                                            // all
                                                                            // permutations
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // queens
                                                                            // once
                                                                            // removed
                    for (Board bo : boardsToBeAdded) {
                        newBoards.add(bo); // add it in to the next list
                    }
                } else {
                    foundBoards.add(b); // if we have no impact, we have a
                                        // solution
                }
            }
            if (!foundBoards.isEmpty())
                break;
            boardObjects.clear();
            boardObjects = newBoards;
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum number of super-queens is: " + i);
        ArrayList<String> winningCombinations = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Board board : foundBoards) {
            String createdBoard = board.drawBoard();
            boolean found = false;
            for (String storedBoard : winningCombinations) {
                if (storedBoard.equals(createdBoard))
                    found = true;
            }
            if (!found)
                winningCombinations.add(createdBoard);
        }
        for (String board : winningCombinations) {
            System.out.println(board);
        }
    }
}
```

The end output is:

```
The maximum number of super-queens is: 6
  A B C D E F G H
8|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
7|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|
6|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|
5|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
4|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
3|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|
2|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
1|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|

  A B C D E F G H
8|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
7|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
6|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
5|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
4|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|
3|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
2|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|
1|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|

  A B C D E F G H
8|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
7|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
6|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
5|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|
4|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
3|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
2|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|
1|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|

  A B C D E F G H
8|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
7|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
6|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
5|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|
4|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
3|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|
2|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|
1|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|

  A B C D E F G H
8|_|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|
7|Q|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
6|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|
5|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
4|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|_|
3|_|_|_|_|_|_|Q|_|
2|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
1|_|_|_|Q|_|_|_|_|
```

I've removed the duplicates and made a nice board printing method. don't remember the exact math, but this highlights 40 possible locations. There are others, just by looking, but we've found a fair chunk of them already! From here, we can gently shift individual queens around. From a cursory look, each board has a single piece that can be moved to 3 additional spaces, so now we know there are probably about 160 solutions.

#### Conclusions

With this application, the run-time on my machine was less than a second, meaning that if we attached this to a standard queens application, the additional knight's brute-forcing would have no impact on that process and have almost the same run-time. In addition, because only 6-piece puzzles are possible, we know that your eventual application run will finish its finding at the 6th piece being placed, as no more solutions are possible, since there are no viable 7-piece and 8-piece solutions.

In other words, finding the maximum super-queen layout is likely actually shorter than the maximum queen layout due to the additional restrictions!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to brute-force such a question is a good way to get a feel for it. So I won't suggest looking up pre-cooked solutions at first.

One little remark though: I don't see the reason for the condition `if (i != 0 || j != 0) {` that you have there. You are working on Java arrays. Instead of 1 through 8, they go 0 through 7, but the 0 is the first column, you should not eliminate it, otherwise it's only a 7x7 board.

---

First, let me address your technical question: how to calculate the knight positions.

Take a sheet of quad paper, put a queen somewhere not less than two squares away from the edge. Then mark the end positions of a knight-move from it.

You'll end up with just 8 squares that need to be considered. There is no point in doing a 3x3 loop to find them. A better idea would be to prepare a static array with the relative coordinates of the knight moves - an array of 8 pairs of numbers - and loop on that. So you have only an 8-step loop. In each step of the loop, check for bounds (0 ≤ X + Xoffset < 8, 0 ≤ Y + Yoffset < 8 ), and you have the knight coordinates.

---

Second, there is no point checking the part of the board that's ahead of you. Since you have not covered the next row and those below it, there is no point in looking for queens there. The implications of this:

- You'll never put another queen in the same row where you have just marked a queen position (because you threaten it horizontally). This means that if you mark a queen, you should use `continue` to break out of the inner loop to the next row.
- You don't need `checkrow()`. When you start a row, there is no queen ahead of you. And if you followed the above bullet point, there is no queen on your back, either.
- When you use `checkcolumn`, you start at row 0, but you can finish at the row before the one you are on (`i-1`). There are still no queens in the rows below you! The same is true for the diagonal checks.
- Earlier I said that you need to prepare and check 8 knight positions. But now you know there is no queen at the knight positions ahead of you. So you only need to prepare an array with four knight positions - the ones above your position.

---

But most importantly... once you have finished and you have your queens in positions and print the board: you have a single solved board. You have proved that this number of queens is possible. But is it the highest number possible? You have not checked what happens if you don't put a queen on the first square of the first row, but on the second. Perhaps this will allow you to put in an extra queen later. And what about the queen in the second row? Maybe if you moved that, you would be able to put a queen somewhere below where you couldn't before?

So, now you have to actually do the same thing over again, changing one decision every time and working from there. In effect, you have many potential boards. Why? Because there may be more than one valid position on each row where you put that row's queen. So you have decided to put it in the first valid position. But what if you decide to put it in the second valid position? Or leave that row empty? Each such decision is followed by another set of decisions on the next row.

The different boards created by different decisions form a decision tree. The problem for you to consider, therefore, is how to work such a tree out. How to write your decision trail and then backtrack, change, fill another board and count the queens at each level. People here suggested recursion, because it lends itself nicely to such problems. Or you can keep a stack of decisions if you want. You can eliminate some of the potential boards based on symmetries.

I suggest you first make sure you understand your single board well, and then consider how to represent your decision tree and how to traverse it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions here.

The first is: how many knight-queens can be placed on an nxn chessboard?  Since a k-piece solution can trivially be reduced to a k-1 piece solution, it makes sense to start from the upper bound.  That is, look for an n-piece solution, if that fails look for an n-1 piece solution, and so forth.

The second question is: how should I look for a k-piece solution?  There are two classic strategies: depth-first and breadth-first.  In the former, you consider one vertex of the search tree at a time and use backtracking on failure.  In the latter, you consider one complete level of the search tree at a time.

Something that can make a great deal of difference to your search is to account for symmetry (in this case, rotations and reflections).

The third (implicit) question is: what is a good representation here?  If your chess-boards are less than 8x8 in size then a 64-bit bit-pattern will do very nicely!

In practical terms, try to separate the three levels of your problem as far as you can.  If you don't, you'll find that a choice in one level will severely limit your options at another level.