# Where to start on a "generate and test" approach using Java

Tags: java, tree, depth-first-search, n-queens

I am required to solve the "N Queens" problem using a generate and test approach in Java, so basically if N=8 my program must generate the 8^8 possible lists and test each one to return the 92 distinct lists that result in a solution to the problem. I must also use a DFS algorithm with backtracking to enumerate the possibilities.

To provide an example, list (2,4,6,8,3,1,7,5) means that the first queen is column 1 row 2, the second is column 2 row 4, the third is column 3 row 6...and so on.

The two main things preventing me from making headway on this are:

1) I have no idea how to generate every possible list of length N (and integers size N or less) in Java

2) I don't really understand how once I have all these lists, to abstract them to a datatype that can be traversed with a DFS algorithm.

I'm not begging someone to do my homework for me, more I'd like a conceptual walkthrough of how #2 can be thought of and a (somewhat) tangible example of how given an input N I can generate all N^N lists.

Comment: It is not 8^8 possible layouts, it is 8! layouts. You would ostensibly eliminate (11111111) as a possibility, as each queen must be on a unique row. To generate all possible nQueens, do a for loop of 1-8 for column 1, then the remaining 7 spaces for column two, and so on. Final result is about 40K possibilities, much smaller than 8^8. After that, you run the algorithm on each queen, checking its diagonals for intercepts, to yield the results.

Comment: I did a writeup on the 8-superqueens problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773589/confused-about-writing-a-program-for-placing-some-modified-queen-type-pieces-on/26433630#26433630 It's a more complex problem but the logic is similar.